# android button shrinks in smaller screen devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layout. There is a button at the bottom id=btn with a text in it, this button looks fine on bigger screen handsets , but on smaller screens it looks like a line, with no visible text. How to fix it?

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <!-- Name Label -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img_na" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="Name:"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hide_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="hideBtnClicked"
            android:text="hidden   (change)"
            android:textColor="@color/editRed"
            android:textSize="12dip"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Name Value -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- Address Label -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:text="Address:"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hide_addr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="hideBtnClicked"
            android:text="hidden   (change)"
            android:textColor="@color/editRed"
            android:textSize="12dip"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Address Value -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- Phone Number Label -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:text="Phone:"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hide_ph"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="hideBtnClicked"
            android:text="hidden   (change)"
            android:textColor="@color/editRed"
            android:textSize="12dip"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Phone Value -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- Location Value -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/distance"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:text="to retain heigth" />

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: Thanks for suggesting scrollvew but I want the button to be visible at all times, So I dont want to make it scollable. Secondly the content is also not very long to make it scrollable , I am running short of only a few dps. So I would want to avoid scroll view. I just want the whole of content to shrink a bit height wise depending on the screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ScrollView to allow the content to scroll into every screen size.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
       yes use scroll view 


  <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fillViewport="true" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:background="#ffffff"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button6"

    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding, but as i mentioned in the edit, I dont want to use scrollview for the the mentioned reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to check `GridLayout` for such a case. However GridLayout requires `API Level 14` or above! and any device working on API Level less than 14 wont be compatible with your app.

Also you can use v7 gridlayout library for API level less than 14. I think you can find an example through Google pretty easy!